# Getting Error : "You must declare "ids" as a unique array of fields in your source settings." while trying to migrate for paragraph in Drupal 8

Tags: 8, migrations

I have created a yml configuration for migration from CSV source into drupal using composer. After running the "drush migrate:import mbe_book_paragharphs", I am getting the error as You must declare "ids" as a unique array of fields in your source settings.

I am using migrate_source_csv 8.x-3.1

```
id: mbe_book_paragharphs
migration_group: mbe_migrations
label: 'Import book paragraph'
source:
  plugin: csv
  path: '/var/www/html/drupal/author.csv'
  header_row_count: 1
  ids: [id]
process:
  field_mbe_title: Title
  field_mbe_author: Author
destination:
  plugin: 'entity_reference_revisions:paragraph'
  default_bundle: mbe_book
migration_dependencies: null
```

I need help on how to resolve this issue

[image: paragraph yml]

[image: node yml]

[image: paragraph csv]

[image: professor csv]

In the YML configuration file, instead of "ids", i was using "keys" before but was getting the same error

Comment: When you change the ID keys in a previsously installed migration file, the existing `migration_map_XXXX` database table no longer matches the migration definition. The worklow here is rollback -> uninstall -> drop old migration_map_xxx table -> update YML -> reinstall.

Answer (score 4):

As the error message suggests, `ids` needs to be an array, e.g.

```
source:
  plugin: csv
  path: '/var/www/html/drupal/author.csv'
  header_row_count: 1
  ids: 
    id:
      type: integer
```

Do note that you're in a YML file here; it looks like you might have tried to use PHP array syntax.

Comment: does not work. Issue persists. Getting same error message

Comment: You’ll need to provide some more information- the above pattern has always worked fine for me, there are examples of the same in core, and so on.

Comment: I have added the code image as well as the csv image. Can you tell me where I am going wrong

Comment: You didn't change your code so it follows the same format as in the answer. It's not going to work until you do that

Comment: I had made the changes and got the same error thats why I reverted the changes suggested by you

Comment: Something else is wrong then - as I said, the format of the file in the answer is correct. You can see for yourself by searching the core codebase for the string `ids:`, and looking in migration related YML files that contain it. The format in your original question was wrong, and the format in your question currently is wrong. You need to use the format demonstrated in the answer, or it won't work.

Comment: After applying the changes as per your suggestion, the error I am getting now is "The ids must be a flat array with unique string values".